# A-Frame Canvas texture default color white in VR-mode

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I am applying a canvas as a texture to a plane. And it looks fine (The background is white by default) if I am displaying it within a browser itself.

But as I change to Virtual Reality Mode the background of the canvas is changing to black.

I know that i can place a white rect to have a white background, but this is not feasible due to performance issues.

Are there any other solutions to tackle this problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try filling in the canvas as white (fillRect), or adding a background to the scene itself (`<a-sky color="#FFF">`). Let me know if that works, or provide a JSFiddle for us to play around.